# How do you access the all of the NSLog statements?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, debugging

I have an application which is producing an error very intermittently, I am trying to run it down with an NSLog statement in swift. However, after I have noticed the bug has occured, when I hook up my iPhone to review the logs in the Devices window. I only see about 5 minutes worth of statements from various applications. Is there a way to get the history past what automatically comes up? Is there a way to get your applications NSLog statements only?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it from Swift, but we sometimes use [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) from Obj-C. It will log to a local Mac application instead of the console on the device. Alternatively, we sometimes log to a file and then transfer the file via email.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Bugfender](http://bugfender.com), it's a product we have built to solve this problem. We had the same problem, especially when delivering beta apps to our customers, so we decided to make a product to solve this problem.

With Bugfender you will be able to get the device logs without any need to connect the device to your computer.

It's easy to integrate and you can choose which devices you want to get the logs from. Our service works offline and online, we have spent a lot of time to make it reliable and easy to use.